# SPOIL rootme TCP back to college challenge: sending the right result after converting it into bytes but I keep getting wrong answer

Tags: python, sockets, byte

In this challenge, I have to read what the server is printing, extract 2 integer values val1 & val2, calculate the square root of val1 and multiply by val2 and send the result to the server.

I managed to do all that but I keep getting wrong answer.
Here's my code:

```py
import math
import socket

HOST = "challenge01.root-me.org"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 52002  # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(data)
    print("a="+str(data[171:174]))
    print("b="+str(data[191:195]))
    a=math.sqrt(int(data[171:174]))
    b=int(data[191:195])*a
    print(b)
    c=bytes(str(b)+"\n",'utf-8')
    print("c="+c.decode())

    # s.send(c.encode())
    s.send(c)
    data2=s.recv(1024)

print(f"Received {data2!r}")
```

Sending the result to the server requires you to convert the result into bytes along with "\n", so I thought maybe the conversion went wrong, but when I convert it back to string I get the same result.

[Example of execution of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KLlt.png)

So I really can't see the problem.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Not enough information.  What is the content of `data`?  Are you getting any error messages?  Add them *as text* if so.  Is the server information real? I can ping the host but can't connect to the port.

Comment: That sounds like the final result.  What is the content of `data`, not `data2`?  What output do you get for your prints?  Edit the question with complete information, not as a comment.

Comment: hope it's more helpful ! @MarkTolonen

Comment: The execution text should be added **as text** to the question; but otherwise, the answer looks correct.  Do you have any other information about the format of the result that is sent back to the server?  Is the result supposed to be rounded to a certain decimal place?  Also your script output doesn't match the script shown so make sure they agree.

Comment: Sorry about the execution that wasn't matching the code. I just edited it ! As for the result, I believe it shouldn't be rounded. I tried sending the integer part but it didn't work as well

Comment: Otherwise, your code looks correct.  lf they didn’t document clearly how to send the result, I don’t know how else to help

Comment: Okay i just noticed that the result must be rounded. I'm really sorry for the misunderstanding. At least, now I know how to post on stackoverflow. Thanks again ! @MarkTolonen

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to round `b` by 2 decimals. Make a round variable and use the `round()` function: `r=round(b, 2)`

```
import math
import socket

HOST = "challenge01.root-me.org"  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 52002  # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(data)
    print("a="+str(data[171:174]))     
    print("b="+str(data[191:195]))
    a=math.sqrt(int(data[171:174]))
    b=int(data[191:195])*a
    r=round(b, 2)
    print(r)
    c=bytes(str(r)+"\n",'utf-8')
    print("c="+c.decode())

    # s.send(c.encode())
    s.send(c)
    data2=s.recv(1024)

print(f"Received {data2!r}")
```